# Flash / HTML5 player for MMS streaming

Tags: html, streaming, mms, windows-media-server

I need to play MMS audio streaming with a web base flash or HTML5 player for a live web radio. Is there a solution that works with all borwsers?

Comment: MMS audio for browsers? In what format?

Comment: HI I use WMS (Windows Media) server

Answer (score 1):

Use the VLC Player Plugin with the HTML5 `embed` tag for cross-browser compatibility:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="300" height="200" target="mms://127.0.0.1:554/video" />
```

Use a browser specific plugin for cross-OS compatibility.

**References**

- [HTML5 Video: Fallbacks](http://en.flossmanuals.net/_booki/ogg-theora/ch014_html5.html)
- [VLC Documentation: Web Plugin](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin/)
- [VLC Plugin Demo](http://people.videolan.org/~dionoea/vlc-plugin-demo/)
- [Media Player Connectivity Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mediaplayerconnectivity/)
- [Retired Addressing Schemes](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/schemes)
- [Windows Media Player Protocol Rollover](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/randomnumber/archive/2008/08/18/windows-media-player-protocol-rollover.aspx)
- [RTSP](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Networking/RTSP)